# Kodak Carestream PACS integration

Tags: com

just a shot in the dark here.
Does anyone here have any experience with coding an integration into Kodak's carestream (pacs) product?

I am trying to integrate into their COM server, but hitting issues with saving Key Images.

I just want to see if this is a suitable forum for asking carestream related queries.

Thanks!
Craig

Comment: Hi. I want to integrate too... Wanna talk?